# Transferring files from Linux server to other multiple Linux machines through SSH-key authentication

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, fedora

I work as an IT specialist in a company that has many branches that work with Linux Fedora 35 OS. Sometimes when we need to configure something across all machines across all branches we need to send config files and other type of files to all machines.

I have a Fedora 39 machine which I use to perform this task.

I wrote a Bash script to send public SSH-key of my Fedora server to all the machines across these branches so I would have SSH-key based authentication access to all these machines. Then, I wrote the following Bash script to send the files. The script loops through a text file that contains a column of all the gateway IP addresses. For each IP address, the script pings machines with end prefixes range of 10 to 22 (machines' IP addresses pattern) and if a machine IP address pings back, the script will transfer files using SSH-key based authentication. The script has a timeout for the ping and Rsync functions.

The script works perfectly fine until it loops through certain IP addresses and it freezes and the script can even stop.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Specify the default location for the SSH key
SSH_KEY=/root/.ssh/id_rsa

current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
source_file="/home/abdulrahman/firefox-redhat-default-prefs.js"
remote_dir="/usr/lib64/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/"

source_file2="/etc/hosts"
remote_dir2="/etc/"

source_file3="/home/abdulrahman/Tamweely-CA.cer"
remote_dir3="/"

# Function to ping an IP address
ping_ip() {
    local ip=$1
    # Remove non-numeric characters from the IP address
    ip=$(echo "$ip" | tr -cd '[:digit:].')
    # Check if the IP address is empty after cleaning
    if [ -z "$ip" ]; then
        echo "Skipping invalid IP address."
        return
    fi
    ping -W 5 -c 1 "$ip" > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "IP address $ip is up."
    return 0
    else
        echo "IP address $ip is down."
    return 1
    fi
}

send_file(){
    local source_file=$1
    local ip_addr=$2
    local remote_dir=$3

    #scp -l "250" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" "$source_file" "root@$ip_addr:$remote_dir" 
    rsync -avmzPR -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=60" --progress "$source_file" "root@$ip_addr:$remote_dir"

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "File is sent successfully to $ip_addr" | tee -a "/home/abdulrahman/scs/reports/file_report_$current_date.txt"    
    else        
        echo "Failed to send file to $ip_addr" | tee -a "/home/abdulrahman/scs/reports/file_report_$current_date.txt"
    fi      
}


# Specify the path to your text file
IP_FILE="/home/abdulrahman/scs/ip_addresses.txt"
#IP_FILE="/home/abdulrahman/scs/ip_address2.txt"


# Check if the file exists
if [ ! -f "$IP_FILE" ]; then
    echo "Error: File $IP_FILE not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Initialize an array to store background process IDs
#declare -a bg_pids

# Read each line (IP address) from the file and perform an action
while IFS= read -r ip_address; do
    # You can replace the echo statement with the action you want to perform
    for device_ip in ${ip_address%.*}.{10..22}; do 
        if ping_ip "$device_ip"; then
        send_file "$source_file" "$device_ip" "$remote_dir"   
        send_file "$source_file2" "$device_ip" "$remote_dir2"  
        send_file "$source_file3" "$device_ip" "$remote_dir3" 
        #Store the background process ID
            #bg_pids+=($!)  
        fi
    done    
done < "$IP_FILE"

# Wait for all background processes to complete
#for pid in "${bg_pids[@]}"; do
#  wait "$pid"
#done
```

The `ip_addresses.txt` file is as follows:

```
192.168.119.1   
192.168.3.1 
192.168.2.1 
192.168.7.1 
192.168.6.1 
192.168.4.1 
192.168.20.1    
192.168.110.1   
192.168.13.1    
192.168.21.1    
172.27.13.1 
192.168.114.1   
172.27.15.1 
172.27.16.1 
172.27.17.1 
172.28.18.1 
172.27.19.1 
172.27.20.1 
172.27.21.1 
172.27.22.1 
172.28.23.1 
172.27.24.1 
172.27.25.1 
172.27.26.1 
172.27.27.1 
172.27.28.1 
172.27.29.1 
172.27.30.1 
172.27.31.1 
172.27.32.1 
172.27.33.1 
172.28.34.1 
172.28.35.1 
172.27.36.1 
172.28.37.1     
172.28.38.1 
172.27.39.1 
172.27.40.1 
172.27.41.1 
172.28.42.1 
172.28.43.1 
172.27.44.1 
172.27.45.1 
172.27.46.1 
172.28.47.1 
172.27.48.1 
172.27.49.1 
172.27.50.1 
172.27.51.1 
172.28.53.1 
172.28.54.1 
172.27.56.1 
172.27.57.1 
172.28.58.1 
172.27.59.1 
172.27.60.1 
172.27.61.1 
172.28.63.1 
172.27.64.1 
172.28.65.1 
172.28.66.1 
172.28.67.1 
172.28.68.1 
172.27.69.1 
172.27.70.1 
172.27.71.1 
172.28.72.1 
172.28.73.1 
172.28.74.1 
172.27.75.1 
172.27.76.1 
172.27.77.1 
172.27.78.1 
172.27.79.1 
172.27.80.1 
172.27.81.1 
172.27.82.1 
172.28.83.1 
172.27.84.1 
172.27.85.1 
172.27.86.1 
172.28.87.1 
172.28.88.1 
172.28.89.1 
172.27.90.1 
172.27.91.1 
172.27.92.1 
172.28.93.1 
172.28.94.1 
172.28.95.1 
172.28.96.1 
172.27.97.1 
172.27.98.1 
172.27.99.1 
172.27.100.1    
172.27.101.1    
172.27.102.1    
172.28.103.1    
172.28.104.1    
172.28.105.1    
172.28.106.1    
172.28.107.1    
172.28.108.1    
172.28.109.1    
172.28.110.1    
172.27.111.1    
172.28.112.1    
172.27.113.1    
172.27.114.1    
172.27.115.1    
172.27.116.1    
172.27.117.1    
172.28.118.1    
172.28.119.1    
172.27.120.1    
172.27.121.1    
172.27.122.1    
172.27.123.1    
172.27.124.1    
172.27.125.1    
172.27.126.1    
172.27.127.1    
172.27.128.1    
172.28.129.1    
172.27.130.1    
172.28.131.1    
172.28.132.1    
172.28.133.1    
172.28.134.1    
172.28.135.1    
172.27.136.1    
172.28.137.1    
172.28.138.1    
172.27.139.1    
172.27.140.1    
172.27.141.1    
172.27.142.1    
172.27.143.1    
172.28.144.1    
172.27.145.1    
172.28.146.1    
172.28.147.1    
172.27.148.1    
172.28.149.1    
172.27.150.1    
172.28.151.1    
172.28.152.1    
172.28.153.1    
172.27.154.1    
172.28.155.1    
172.27.156.1    
172.28.157.1    
172.28.158.1    
172.28.159.1    
172.28.160.1    
172.27.161.1    
172.28.162.1    
172.28.163.1    
172.27.164.1    
172.27.165.1    
172.27.166.1    
172.27.167.1    
172.28.168.1    
172.27.169.1    
172.27.170.1    
172.28.171.1    
172.28.172.1    
172.28.173.1    
172.28.174.1    
172.28.175.1    
172.27.176.1    
172.28.177.1    
172.28.178.1    
172.28.179.1    
172.28.180.1    
172.28.181.1    
172.27.182.1    
172.28.183.1    
172.27.184.1    
172.27.185.1    
172.28.186.1    
172.28.187.1    
172.27.188.1    
172.28.189.1    
172.28.190.1    
172.27.191.1    
172.27.192.1    
172.28.193.1    
172.27.194.1    
172.27.195.1    
172.27.196.1    
172.27.197.1    
172.28.198.1    
172.28.199.1    
10.173.0.1  
10.172.1.1  
10.173.2.1  
10.173.3.1  
10.173.4.1
```

How can I adjust the script to be time-efficient and work perfectly?

What I have tried as you can see for the commented lines is I made each loop process work in the background. But I still can't put my finger on the problem or see how to fix it.

Comment: Your script is really rather too complex to allow us to guess what's wrong, particularly without access to your environment. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Tangentially, [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: What does `ps` reveal when the script gets stuck? Have you tried running it with `bash -x`?

Comment: No, I haven't tried using ```bash -x```. Will try it.

Comment: Instead of reinvent the wheel you could use something like **ansible** for this. It's specially designed for such tasks. Much more powerful, much more stable

Answer (score 0):

Your commented lines didn't work because you didn't use the `&` symbol. So each job is still blocking. Only with `&` you can make a code block run in the background.

And the right way should be:

```bash
check_and_send() {
    local device_ip=$1
    if ping_ip "$device_ip"; then
        send_file "$source_file" "$device_ip" "$remote_dir"
        send_file "$source_file2" "$device_ip" "$remote_dir2"
        send_file "$source_file3" "$device_ip" "$remote_dir3"
        #Store the background process ID
        #bg_pids+=($!)
    fi
    # adding some information to log file maybe better
}

while IFS= read -r ip_address; do
    check_and_send $device_ip &
done < "$IP_FILE"

wait
```

I think the blocking is mainly caused by `ping`, because sending files shouldn't take much time.

Comment: The OP is asking why their script is not working, not how to make it more efficient.

Comment: @tripleee I think he said "How can I adjust the script to be time-efficient and work perfectly".

Comment: @tripleee I overlooked his last 2 lines. Updated my answer.